# Is it safe to run `sentry upgrade –noinput` every time Sentry is restarted?

Tags: sentry

In the context of running Sentry in OpenShift/Kubernetes and automating the upgrade process I'm considering running `sentry upgrade --noinput` every time the pod is recreated (before running `sentry run web`). Is this safe? In other words, are repeated runs of `sentry upgrade --noinput` completely passive and harmless when no version change has taken place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentry's core developer [Matt Robenolt](https://forum.sentry.io/u/matt) gave the [answer](https://forum.sentry.io/t/is-it-safe-to-run-sentry-upgrade-noinput-every-time-sentry-is-restarted/2808/3):

> Yes, it is perfectly safe and idempotent.